# Given a map of type Map<K, List<V>>, how to update value within List<V> using Java streams?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am receiving the resposne from some API which is of type:

```
public class Response {

    private String role;
    private String permission;
  
    // Setters and getters
}
```

value of `Role` could be something like `"Admin"`, `"User"` etc and value of permission is something like `"R-4"`, `"C-44"` etc. `"R-"` indicates Region and `"C-"` indicates country.
So initially I constructed Map<String, Set> by doing:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> initialMap= responseList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Reponse::getRole, HashMap::new, 
    Collectors.mapping(Reponse::getPermission, Collectors.toSet()))
);
```

But for my application, I want map to be `Map<String, Set<Long>>` which indicate Role and respective countries associated with that role. Basically, I want to remove `"R-"` and `"C-"` from the Set which is value of `hashmap`. When value is something like `"R-4"` then I want to remove `"R-"` and use id which is `4` in this example and pass this id to database to get the `List<Long> countries` and add it into value of `hashmap`.  When value is something like `"C-44"` then I want to remove `"C-"` and add that id into value of `hashmap`.
One approach could be manually iterating over each entry of `initialMap` and then getting it's corresponding `Set<String>` value and then again iterating over `Set<String>` to get `String` value and then converting it to `Long`. I was thinking is there any better way to do this using Streams? can I directly construct `Map<String, Set<Long>>` from my initial `reponseList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the main issue here is not with parsing the id of region/country but rather with combining `List<Long>` containing multiple country IDs *per regionId* retrieved from some DB/repository, and a single country ID from the permission `C-###`.

This may be resolved using [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) available in Java 9+.  Also, a separate function `streamOfCountryIDs` needs to be implemented to map the response's permission into a `Stream<Long>` for this collector:

```java
Map<String, Set<Long>> converted = responses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Response::getRole,
                Collectors.flatMapping(MyClass::streamOfCountryIDs, Collectors.toSet())
        ));

System.out.println(converted);
```

```java
// MyClass
private static Stream<Long> streamOfCountryIDs(Response response) {
    String permission = response.getPermission().toUpperCase();
    if (permission.startsWith("R-")) {
        return countryRepo.getCountriesByRegion(Long.parseLong(permission.substring(2)))
            .stream();
    } else if (permission.startsWith("C-")) {
        return Stream.of(Long.parseLong(permission.substring(2)));
    }
    // log bad permission and return empty stream or throw an exception if needed
    System.out.println("Bad permission: '" + permission + "'");
    return Stream.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Map<String, Set<String>> initialMap= responseList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Response::getRole, HashMap::new, 
    Collectors.mapping((Response res) -> Long.parseLong(res.getModifiedPermission()), Collectors.toSet()))
);
```

with `getModifiedPermission()` being a function which removes the prefix from Permission.